# ROTAS ANGULAR 2+

Tags: angular

Eu separei meus módulos de rota:
1 - product.routing.module.ts Onde tenho a rota de /product e suas filhas /product/new /product/edit
2 - app.routing.module.ts Onde tenho as rotas raizes da minha aplicação /orders /customers mas não coloquei a rota /product

Quando eu coloquei no meu app.module.routing.ts
{ path: ‘**’, component: PageNotFoundComponent }

Quando eu acesso minha rota /products aparece o PageNotFoundComponent

Ele só funciona se eu colocar path: ‘*’ ( com um asterisco ) mas não carrega as rotas filhas de /products, o que devo fazer?

HELP ;/

Comment: Vice deve utilizar o lazymodule na app.routing.module.ts. ele ficara parecido com isso: export const AppRouter: Routes = { path: 'product', loadChildren: './product/product.module#ProductsModule' },

Comment: Então só funciona com lazyloading?